# upload server files using form

Tags: php

i have a very simple form but my situation is different.i dont want to browse from computer .my files are located at my server so how can i browse server files in form field.if i cant browse can i give any location so that it can be uploaded again to my server but at different location and with all different parameters so i dont want to use move method.

i dont want to use remote url upload method as with remote url method i cant check the file type and if can check using curl then also my form processing script is not accepting that links as it is not a valid file format.any idea to sort out this issue will be great help

i dont want for users i have to submit those files using form

```
 <form action="fup.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  File to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile"><br>
  Notes about the file: <input type="text" name="note"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!
   </form>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `<input type="file" />` to do this, but you can use the PHP function [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get the list of files in a particular folder and then present them to the user however you want.

Comment: @travesty i dont want for users i have to submit those files using form

Comment: You said that you want to be able to browse server files in a form field. By "users," I meant anyone looking at the form. You can put the list of files in a dropdown list or something and then choose from that list, then submit the form and in your `fup.php` script, take the form value and do whatever you want (copy, move, etc). If this isn't what you want, you'll have to clarify exactly what kind of interaction you're looking for and your expected result.

Comment: @Travesty3 i have 10000 mp3 in my server i want to upload them all one by one with different form processing so i have clear details of all those files but i dont know how to upload them again to server with my new processor. earlier it was in the form of forum now it is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unclear on this. I'm not sure why you're doing this with HTML at all instead of just modifying the files directly on your server.

I'm also not sure what details you are modifying on each file:

- What kind of details are you modifying?
- Where are these details stored?
- How would you go about modifying those details if the file had been uploaded via form submission?

As a starting point, let me give you an example of my initial suggestion, and then you can tell me exactly why it won't work for you.

**fup.php:**

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"] === "Press")
    {
        $file = {$_POST["upfile"]};
        $notes = $_POST["note"];

        $path = "/path/to/folder";

        // EDIT: Checking to make sure extension is mp3
        if (strtolower(pathinfo("{$path}/{$file}", PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) !== "mp3")
            sys_back("Unavailable mp3 format");

        `cp {$path}/{$file} /path/to/new/folder/{$file}`;
        // do something with $notes
    }
?>
<form action="fup.php" method="POST">
    File to upload:
    <select name="upfile">
<?php   $files = scandir("/path/to/folder");
        foreach ($files as $file)
            echo "\t\t<option>{$file}</option>\n";
?>  </select><br />
    Notes about the file: <input type="text" name="note"/><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Press" /> to upload the file!
</form>
```

Since you mentioned that you will be going through your 10,000 files one-by-one, it would probably be helpful for the dropdown to automatically have the next file selected by default, so you don't have to look through a 10,000 item list every time. You can do this by changing the `foreach` loop to something more like this:

```
$selectNext = false;
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo "\t\t<option". ($selectNext ? " selected" : "") .">{$file}</option>\n";
    $selectNext = ($file === $_POST["upfile"]);
}
```

Comment: i tried the same thing earlier as well as the files are located in server the error i am getting .something like unavialable mp3 format as i am just passing the link.

Comment: If you could show the code you are using when that error is produced, I can help you figure out what's wrong there. You probably need to open the file and pass the handle to your function instead of passing the path to the file.

Comment: it is same code as above very simple php upload which can handle just browse upload .if you can help in opening remote file and upload it will be a great help

Comment: There is no part of the above code that will produce an error regarding an unavailable mp3 format. You keep talking about opening a file on the server and then uploading it to the server. That's not uploading at all. Uploading is when you transfer files from one device to another. In order to upload it, you would first have to download it. You're talking about ***copying*** the file from one location to another. If you want to upload the file via form submission, you will first have to download the file. Again, where is the code that produces the mp3 format error?

Comment: if (!eregi(".mp3$",$_FILES['upfile']['name'])) {

    sys_back('Unavaible mp3 format');
  }

Comment: It looks like all that is doing is making sure that the filename ends in ".mp3". But `eregi` is deprecated (you shouldn't use it), and you just need to look at the current file instead of `$_FILES`. See the edit in my answer, under the comment `// EDIT: Checking to make sure extension is mp3`.

Comment: If you used my exact code and you are still getting that error, then you must not have selected an mp3 file. Update your question with the exact code you are using (**all** of it) and I will try to help you. Here is a working example of my code: http://codepad.org/qtNkELrk

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If you want users to actually copy/move files from your server to another path into same machine, you'll have to:

1. prompt the users with a browser dialog, which will let them pick a file from a remote dir;
2. send such path to your server, where you'll validate the data [e.g. accepting only archives coming from a given directory in order not to mess with filesystem];
3. once you have the chosen path, you can check for MIME types / etc., then copy/move archive and answer back the client with operation result.

If your script "cannot accept links", change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse server images using `classic file manager`

I also used that for same purpose

http://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/archives/master